# How do individual masses 'add up' to create a gravitational field?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, popular-science

The combined mass of the Earth is responsible for its local gravitational force.

However, this combined mass is made up from of lots and lots (and lots) of atoms, each with their own individual mass values.

How do these masses combine or 'work together' to create the gravitational field? Does matter become gravitationally aligned? Would it mean that individual masses have to facilitate some kind of information exchange?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Gravity doesn't have two different poles like magnetism, it is always attractive.

Comment: Ok, I deleted the 'does matter somehow become gravitationally aligned like electrons in a permanent magnet' bit. But a) that was an analogy and b) just because you don't like one part of a question doesn't mean you should discredit the rest of it.

Comment: Still doesn't make more sense. What does "gravitationally aligned" mean? The gravitational  fields of the individual masses just *add* to each other, like the electric fields when you charge something. What process do you think has to be explained here?

Comment: There's no cooperative phenomena.  Each bit of mass acts on its own.  All the individual forces from each bit adds to form the net force.

Comment: @garyp, saying it is not a co-operative phenomena and then saying all the bits add up to form a net force is contradictory. What I was asking is how the masses add up. Surely they must combine through some effect, otherwise I would only feel the effect of one quark at a time, which I guess wouldn't even be able to overcome the electrostatic effect

Comment: I'm sorry  ... vocabulary problem.  "Cooperative behavior" is physics lingo used to describe behavior that is emergent from interactions between individual particles.  Gravity does not have that.  I don't quite understand the difficulty.  Imagine three objects in a line, A, B, and C.  Suppose the gravitational force on A due to B is 1 N, and the gravitational force on A due to C is 2 N.  The total gravitational force on A is 3 N.   It just adds.  That it works this way is called the *superposition  principle*.  In short: gravitational forces simply add.

Comment: **Does matter become gravitationally aligned?** think of the almost perfect symmetry around each atom, it remains grosso modo only a force going to the center of gravity. Related to the shell theorem. Geometry not cooperation ( or else you may revisit the word on a philosophical and existential basis )

Comment: the tags are  *gravity, quantum-gravity, emergent-properties*. With "*popular-sciences, gravity, emergent-properties*" , this question becomes valid

Comment: ok, thanks - I wasn't aware of the popular-sciences tag

Comment: Doesn't the fact that very massive bodies (stars, planets) tend towards the spherical lend credence to the idea that gravity is an emergent property - i.e. th gravitational field is organizing the mass collectively into the most efficient shape.

Comment: also, doesn't the tendency toward spherical shapes demonstrate the masses have some kind of allignment

Answer (score 1):

Here's the way I understand it. Someone will correct me if I'm wrong I'm sure.
Using the earth as an example, and assuming a constant mass density, for an object outside of the earth’s surface, it appears as if all the mass of the earth is concentrated at its center. This is a form of Gauss’s law for gravitational objects. If you could go to the exact center of the earth, theoretically you would experience a net gravitational force of zero due to the earth. This is because the amount of mass included in a sphere of radius zero centered at the earth’s center is – zero! All the earth's mass is outside your sphere and the net force exerted on you by all that mass is zero. For the gravitational force at any point between the surface and the center, the force would depend on the total mass inside a sphere with the radius of the distance you are from the center of the earth. Any net gravitational force due to the mass outside that sphere is zero.
I've made quite a few simplifying assumptions here to make a point.

Comment: Thankyou, but this doesn't address the question

Comment: @Amphibio : this explains the pseudo alignment toward the gravity center

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late. But I think I understand what the person is asking. let me rephrase the question " Why does the earth attract everything to its center (or in one direction) when the earth is made up of different atoms each one pulling to its own center????"

1. As others have already told, the gravity in simple terms adds up.

Let's assume earth to be made of uniform non-compressible substance(basically a sphere with non-compressible substance). So the density doesn't change. Now let's assume just a line of atoms from u on the surface to the center of the earth and for now, ignore the forces exerted by any other atoms outside this line.

Assume there are N atoms {a1,a2......aN} (including the center atom which is the 'aN' atom) each separated by distance from each other. So the total distance between u and the center atom is  N*d. Now say f is the gravitational force between u and and first atom beside u i.e 'a1'. So the next atom 'a2' will be at 2d from u and its force on u would be 1/4 * f (inverse square law). So the total gravitational force F till a2 would be
= f+ (1/4)f. Similarly, the last one would have (1/N)^2 *f. Thus the total gravitational force on u from the center would be f +(1/4) * f + ..........+ (1/N)^2 * f < ((pi^2)/6) * f. There u have it for a line. Similarly when u consider every atom the resultant force is still toward the center.

Comment: Hello! It is preferable to use MathJax (LaTeX) to display formulas. You can find a tutorial at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Please [edit] your answer accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Newtonian picture: each little bit of mass $\delta m$ creates around itself a gravitational field. This is a vector field; its strength is $G \delta m /r^2$ and the direction towards the mass. The total field at any given place is the sum of all such contributions from all the little bits of mass.

General relativity picture: each little bit of mass causes a small amount of curvature of the local spacetime, and this curvature is passed on to neighbouring parts of spacetime, diminishing as it goes. The total curvature at any one place is the result of all the contributions from all the bits of mass at their various distances, but the curvature contributions add up in a more complicated way, involving a 16-element tensor field and the total is no longer just a linear sum of all the contributing parts.